# how justified is to use reference instead of pointer for the ease of use in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

how justified is to use reference instead of pointer because you can access the members with '.' instead of '`->`' operator.
Like inside the function

```
void func(stStates &states)
{
   states.nextState = 0;
}
```

instead of

```
void func(stStates *states)
{
   states->nextState = 0;
}
```

Comment: the second one doesn't compile. Also references cannot (normally) be null, so you don't need a null check before accessing them

Comment: @UnholySheep: I don't like to start with "references cannot be null" -- it's all the wrong way round. I'd much rather say "pointers may be null and not point to an object". That way round makes it immediately clear that pointers are more complex than references and require a more complex API.

Comment: Sorry. Copy paste mistake. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: In many ways, the use case for `T&` is similar to a non-null `T * const`. If your application doesn't allow the pointer to be null or to be reassigned to another instance, you can use references for clarity and brevity.

Comment: On a scale from 1 to 10, with one end as the best, it's justified to degree 6.28.

Comment: Voted to close as opinion-based.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Gray field. Not really POB.

Answer (score 3):

Use pointers when you need pointers, use references when you don't but don't want to pass by value. The fact that one takes one more character than the other to use should be the least of your concerns.

Comment: Two other concerns:  pointers take up space, and you can have arrays of pointers.

Comment: @stark References have a size, it just can't be obtained with `sizeof` directly. In practice, I don't know of an implementation where it isn't the size of a pointer. And I believe the phrase "Use pointers when you need pointers" covers the concern "you can have arrays of pointers".

Comment: @stark, strictly spoken you can't have array of references, but you can work around by using [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper). [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/627f1f7cde8f575e).

Comment: Perhaps the hierarchy would have been more obvious thus:  Pass by value when you can, use references when you can't (or shouldn't), unless something requires you to use a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  void func(stStates *states)
>  {
>      states->nextState = 0;
>  }
> ```

Writing such code is courageous!

At least you should assert, that no `nullptr` is passed before dereferencing the pointer parameter:

```
void func(stStates *states)
{
   assert(states);
   states->nextState = 0;
}
```

or you handle that smoothly, if you don't require to have a valid instance of `stStates` passed when your function is called:

```
void func(stStates *states)
{
   if(states) {
       states->nextState = 0;
   }
}
```

Neither of these mentioned methods will save you from invalid pointers passed in like:

```
stStates* states; // << uninitialized, points elsewhere
func(states);
```

<sub>Well there may be a compiler warning.</sub>

---

Using a reference on the other hand mostly requires correct initialization at compile time, and avoids the problems stated above.

Though you still can do silly things like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7780504d41cfdb8d), and the compiler won't warn you about it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    int& r = *p;
    r = 42;
}
```

Result:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -Os -Wall -lboost_timer -lboost_system main.cpp && ./a.out
bash: line 7: 26635 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) ./a.out
```

Comment: Perhaps *reckless* rather than *courageous*.

Comment: _Using a reference requires correct initialization at compile time_ ... [not necessarily](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7780504d41cfdb8d)

Comment: @zett42 Good point!

Comment: I would write it like this: When using pointers, it's the responsibility of the function that has pointer parameters to check for valid pointers (!= nullptr), whereas using references it's the responsibility of the caller to pass valid reference arguments.

Comment: @zett42 Adopted. Sorry calling your example silly ;-)

Comment: I think whenever one does something like this, the universe silently reboots after moving one into a parallel universe where this hasn't happened yet ;-)

Comment: @zett42 Sounds like you're an enlightened person. Thank you.

Comment: @user2079303 Somehow, yes.

Comment: Courageous or reckless or both. But when I'm the one to call my function, I guess it can work.  Though I do check for pointers, I just removed that line from the question. Guess I shouldn't have.

Answer (score 2):

As a coding guideline, it is better to use references instead of pointers. When an argument is of a reference type, the function can simply use the object. When an argument is of a pointer type, you always have to add logic to deal with the argument being a NULL pointer.

Comment: Basically, other than a check for nullptr, reference serves only one additional purpose. You can use object.member rather than object->member.

Comment: That is true but it's only a minor issue in the overall scheme of things. If we could use the "." syntax for pointers and the "->" syntax for references, I would still recommend using references.

Comment: Only thing that tells me no to use reference that by looking at code, I don't know if a pointer is being sent to func.  Like func(abcd) where abcd is some variable.